# Google Drive: File Load Error for.ipynb. Permission denied: Google Drive/My Drive/project/code/.ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am working with other colleagues on a project through Google Drive. I need to access this specific project through Drive instead of GitHub because we also have some folders with `data` (that we modify using the `code` folder files). But now, when I try to access the `.ipynb` files that I had created through my local host and Jupyter Lab / Notebook, I get the following error:

> File Load Error for file.ipynb.
> Permission denied: Google Drive/My Drive/project/code/file.ipynb

I have tried several alternatives but I cannot solve it, and I would like to work from my local host instead of loading all the data into google colab.

*Note: I am working on a Mac computer.*

Comment: request access is on for everyone for the folder?

Comment: I have not seen exactly the option request access, but I have allowed anybody with the link to be an editor of the files (from the root folder of the whole project)